# need help setting up variable in Vue.js framework

Tags: javascript, variables, vue.js

i had a javascript website that worked with the react.js framework and i just recently started to rebuild my site with vue.js. im trying to add in some variables but im having a bit of trouble doing so and research didnt help as much as i hoped.

this is what i had in react.js that i want to recreate in vue.js

```
var dataset5=52;

<div className="bar"style={{width:dataset5+"%",backgroundColor:colorset5}}></div>
```

any tips/references will be of great help to me.

thank you

edit:

main.js:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  computed:{
    ball:"ball"  }
}).$mount('#app')
console.log(foo);
```

PulseOverview.Vue:

```
<div class="section sec2">  
  <div id="app">
     <p>{{ball}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you read the Vue documenation? You’ll find your answer here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: i have looked at it before sending and ive tryed to do it the way it shows it in the documentation but just couldnt get it to work. i was hoping for an exaple on here with my code

Comment: Then post what you actually tried.  Posting what you did in React is not helpful because we need to see the **Vue** code that isn't working so that we can help you make the **Vue** code work.  Taking your question at absolute face value, it comes across as "Please turn my React code into Vue code" which is off-topic as it boils down to a code request.

Comment: @zero2987 i put in an edit, didnt think it was good enough code to put in the ask and was actually going to delete but its the closest thing i got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out on my own after 2 days, thanks guys

```
<template>
  ...
    <h2>{{bar1name}}</h2>
    <h3>{{bar2name}}</h3>
  ...
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  props: {
    bar1name:{        
      type: Object, 
      default: function(){
        return('Listening')
      }
    },
    bar2name:{
      type: Object, 
      default: function(){
        return('Problem Solving')
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```